# IOS Search bar that appears below navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am attempting to have a search bar tied to my UISearchController that appears below the navigation bar, similar to this:

[image]

Currently the search bar replaces the title as is common in most/all IOS apps I've seen. I've attempted to control the search bar presentation through a few methods:

1) Creating a new view that sits underneath the nav bar, and assigning the SearchController's search bar to it.

```
//instead of:
//navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
//do this:
searchplaceholder.addSubview(searchBar)
```

However the search bar shows up 1/2 way down the screen.

[image]

2)Second attempt was to move the frame of the search bar to origin:

```
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, searchBar.frame.height)
view.addSubview(searchBar)
resultSearchController?.active = true
```

Looks good initially:

[image]

But as soon as I start typing, the bar jumps low again:

[image]

How can i Hijack the SearchController to present it's bar either in the nav bar without hiding the page title or constrain the search bar to appear right under the nav bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and short of this is that you can not do what I was attempting to do. You create a searchbar that when clicked transitions to a second screen with a searchbar in the header. This provides the cleanest experience compared to what I have listed above.