# iOS - Moving search bar from center to below Navigation Bar by animation (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a search bar that was added to the center of my view controller via interface builder, and I even connected it with a IBOutlet. However, I had to place the search bar in the center of the view controller because there is important information above it.

What I want is that when the search bar is tapped, it should animate to the top, and fix itself below the navigation bar. The reason why I want it to go to the top is because I need more space for the results table View controller to show the results (which drops down when search bar is tapped).

I've looked everywhere but couldn't really find any information on how to fix the search bar below the navigation bar. Please do help!

P.S - similar problem link [IOS Search bar that appears below navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978399/ios-search-bar-that-appears-below-navigation)

Comment: Dont think your description is similar to the one in your link, put your screenshot would help more

Comment: some screenshot make us to visualize what is really happening.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never uploaded a screenshot here before, how exactly do i do it?

Comment: All I want to know is how to keep the search bar fixed below the navigation bar irrespective of the screen size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add your constraints like the following pictures:

[image] [image]

As you see, 2 of the constraints are drawn with dashes, these constraints have priorities less than 1000, and the reason is that we want the center vertically constraint and anchors to top constraint to be mutually exclusive:

1. One that anchors the search bar to the vertical center of the view.
2. One that anchors the search bar to the top of the view.

And because we want the search bar to be centered vertically initially, we assign a priority of **999** to that constraint (constraint number 1), and a priority of **1** to the other one.

You can set the priorities by clicking on the constraint and setting its priority from size inspector on the right, like in the following picture:

[image]

Second, connect these 2 constraints and your search bar to your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!  
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarAnchorToTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarCenterVerticallyConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Third, make your view controller conform to `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol and set it as the delegate of your search bar.

Forth, implement `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method in the following way:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    self.searchBarCenterVerticallyConstraint.priority = 1
    self.searchBarAnchorToTopConstraint.priority = 999

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

All we did here is that we gave `searchBarCenterVerticallyConstraint` a low priority and `searchBarAnchorToTopConstraint` a high priority (we switched their priorities).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi it seems like you understood my question, and this is what I was looking for! However, there are a couple textfields in the space between the nav bar and the search bar. Would this solution still work?

Comment: Yes, this solution only cares about the constraints we are playing with, it doesn't care whether there are other components in between or not. You'll only need to decide whether to make your search bar go over the other components or from behind them.

Comment: Hi, it was working fine but then I had to add two more textfields so had to push the search bar a little further down than the center of the view controller. However, the constraints keep bringing it back up. I have been tinkering with the priority values but it hasn't yet.  Here are the image links of before and after I moved the searchBar - http://imgur.com/6BvgHSn , http://imgur.com/C68fsqx

Comment: solved it by replacing the vertically in container constraint with constraint from searchBar to bottom layout. Thanks for your help though @moe